# Tcp client in xamarin does not connect

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, tcpclient

I have a problem of client doesn't connect to the server. They are on the same port. I have the right IP address. I wrote a similar program in C# and it connects.

How can I solve it?

I have an Entry called "IpAd", where I write the IP address

```cs
private void Connect_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] ip = new string[3];
    ip = IpAd.Text.Split('.');
    for (int i = 0; i<=3;i++)
    {
        if (int.Parse(ip[i]) > 255 || int.Parse(ip[i]) < 0 || IpAd.Text == "")
        {
            Connected.Text = "Incorrect Ip";
            Connected.TextColor = Color.Red;
            return;
        }
    }
    try
    {
        _sender = new TcpClient(IpAd.Text.ToString(), 11000);

        Connected.Text = "Client Online";
        Connected.TextColor = Color.Green;
        
        stream = _sender.GetStream();

        Connected.Text = "Connected";
        Connected.TextColor = Color.Green;
        Can_send = true;
    }
    catch (SocketException ee)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", ee);
        Connected.Text = "Socket Not Connected";
        Connected.TextColor = Color.Red;
    }
    catch
    {
        Connected.Text = "Not Connected";
        Connected.TextColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: "dont connect" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Do you get an error or exception?  Have you verified connectivity between the devices using a browser or other tool?  Are you sure there are no firewall or other networking issues involved?

Comment: the get the socket exception

Comment: please be **specific** about the exception you are getting

Comment: how can I verify connectivity between the devices using a browser?

Comment: I get an exception because it doesnt connect,
exception details:
System.InvalidOperationException
  Message=The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.

Comment: Use the browser on the device and enter the IP address of the server and see if it can connect

Comment: What IP address are you using? Localhost? If so that won't work on Android Emulators use 10.0.2.2 there for localhost (your computer)

Comment: i dont use emulator, i use my phone